# How to get ID of the page included with get_page()?

Tags: posts, shortcode, id, pages

I'm rewriting the question, including exemplary code, I hope it will be easier to understand now.

### 1. My shortcode:

```
    function testid_shortcode( ) {
         global $post;
         return $post->ID;   
    }

    add_shortcode('testid', 'testid_shortcode');
```

### 2. The issue:

I'm using the shortcode on page Example1 [ID=1]:

```
[testid]
```

Then I'm including it on different page Example 2 [ID=2]:

```
$included_page = get_page( $included_id ); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $included_page->post_content);
```

The shortcode returns "1" and "2" on these pages, while I want it to return "1" AND "1", so simply speaking I want it to retrieve the ID (specifically metaboxes) of the "original" page.

Is it possible to fix it somehow? I guess it should be done within the shortcode itself, but have absolutely no idea how. I guess passing a variable with the "original" ID and overwriting the one shortcode gets will do the trick, but how to do that?

Comment: I, at least, can't really understand the question. I think you either need to provide more code, get a bit more specific or rewrite part of the question. What does the actual shortcode look like? Is the shortcode supposed to always return the post_meta from ID = 1 or does it return the post_meta from the page it's on?

Comment: @mrwweb, check the updated question :)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this, I have the same problem where a shortcode function needs to know on what page it was defined. And that page is included (through get_page()) into another: I can only get the post_id from the "hosting" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global $post object is from the current query, so what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

If you always want the shortcode to return the post_meta from ID = 1, then you should just hardcode that into the shortcode like in @Chris_O's answer where you just save a variable that equals 1 and pass that to `get_page()`.

However, it sounds like you're looking for [shortcode attributes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes). Try this:

```
// shortcode function
function testid_shortcode( $atts ) {
    // extract the variables, if there is no ID attr, the default is 1
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 1
    ), $atts ) );
    // set page id to either the id attr which defaults to one.
    $page_id = $id;
    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
    return // ... return something with your shortcode
}
// register the shortcode
add_shortcode( 'testid', 'testid_shortcode' );
```

Then you could use:

```
[testid]
```

To return the post object with ID=1 or

```
[testid id=2]
```

to return the post object with ID=2.

Comment: this is not a bad idea, but I'm going to use this shortcode on different pages, I won't know their IDs and I'm looking for something more back-end related (so I won't have to think about IDs, also I'll never now which page I'm going to include so I'd have to add this attribute everywhere).

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want the first instance of the shortcode to "anchor" the rest (I can't think of a better way to say that). It sounds like maybe you need to mark one page with a metabox or custom field and then query to get other data from that page. Shortcodes are context-aware, but it's much harder (to the point that it's not worth doing) to have pages be aware of shortcodes on them.

Answer (score 1):

### [`get_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) requires the page id to passed via a variable.

Your giving it a string which is causing WordPress to use the variable from the  `global $page->ID` at the time the function is called.

#### Just pass the page id as a variable and it should work fine.

```
$page_id = 1;
$page_data = get_page( $page_id );
```

Comment: I'm getting the right page, but it's being rendered wrongly as it gets ID of the page where I'm including it, not the page where it originally is. I hope the new question will be easier to understand. That's the problem I'm trying to overcome.